# System.FormatException when trying to write to file C#

Tags: c#

I have this simple program which reads one line in text file, parses the content in a dictionnary and then writes that content
to a file.

The above mentionned line in text file is:

> 1433=Member;1064=EndOfDayReportGeneration;5679=1;5678=22;71=20060226000000000;3141=ClrngETL;72=20100301092024000;2144=CH004CR;4059=20060226;1828=20060226;1823=20100301;969=0048;10003=ACME CIMENT INC.;1180=TOUR OM.  ACMECIMENT 222 FRESNO COLLEGE AVE BUR 500, CA, MQ, H82 2P3;1054=true;1055=5143502945;1059=JENNIFER ALLEY;1058=5143502945;1057=TIM BROWN;1056=5143502865;1088=LORD;1089=12;1090=5143502855;773=Optical,Illusion;1144=0000;1195=1;955=ClientAccountProfile;956=ClearingMember;1558=10000;583={17|100};6385=20081208;5049=PPCD;5578=GA;5579=000;6143=20060226;70=000000000;73=20100301;80=092024000;2578=98138000

I get the System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero
and less than the size of the argument list when trying to write to the file.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dicParsed = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("testFormat.txt");
            String line;
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                dicParsed = line.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(part => part.Split('='))
                 .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
                string[] data = line.Split(null);

                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //close the file
            if (sr != null)
            {
                sr.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + except.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Configuration File Parsed");
        }

        using (StreamWriter swLog = new StreamWriter("testLog.txt", true))
        {

            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("TEST "); 
            message.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> paires in dicParsed)
            {                    
                    message.Append(paires.Key.ToString() + "=" + paires.Value.ToString() + ";");
                    Console.WriteLine();
            }

            try
            {
                string test = message.ToString();
                swLog.Write(test, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
} // end class program
```

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: What's up with the `line.Split(null)`? Why are you setting the buffer size of the `StreamWriter` to *4*? Why are you rewriting the dictionary all the time without doing anything with it?

Comment: The code line that throws the error is : swLog.Write(test,true) in the second Try.

Comment: your text has `{17|100}` in it. string.format thinks that that is part of the formatting.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in your code and stepping through line by line, inspecting the values as you go. The reason for the problem will likely become apparent.

Comment: `583={17|100}` in your content. Need to escape the `{}`'s when writing to a method that accepts format parameters.

Comment: @Luaan [`string.Split(null)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) uses _any_ whitespace as a delimiter.

Comment: @DStanley I know that. But what's the point? The value isn't used anywhere. The code is just way too weird.

Comment: @BradChristie You're right - I didn't catch that and removed my comment.  Good catch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `StreamWriter.Write(test, true)`. I don't know why. This will call the [`StreamWriter.Write(string, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxhes7h2(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, which is used to format-print a string (like `Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name)`).

Your `test` string contains a `{17|100}`, not a `{0}`, so it throws. Just use the `Write(string)` overload.

Comment: I think the issue is with the `{17|100}`.  Not that `test` does not have a `{0}` in it.  At least `Console.WriteLine("Hello", 1);` runs just fine, so I assume it would work for `StreamWriter.Write` as well.

Comment: @juharr no. Using `StreamWriter.Write(string)` you can just write a string containing any characters, even containing `{0}` or `{17|100}`. No interpretation of the string whatsoever happens in that case. OP is calling the overload that _does_ do formatting, which most certainly isn't what they want, and that is the cause of the exception.

Comment: I agree that they don't want that overload.  I'm saying that the exception is occurring because of the `{17|100}`, not the lack of a `{0}`.  So instead of "doesn't contain a `{0}`, so it throws" should be "contains `{17|100}`, so it throws"

Comment: Thanks everyone.  The exception in my case was happening because of the {17|100} .  (When I removed that part of the data, the application worked fine).  However,  just using Write(string) allowed the program to work fine even with the {17|100}.

Comment: @juharr I'd expect the exception to be consistent with `Console.WriteLine()`, which throws a different `FormatException`, [namely _"FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format"_](http://ideone.com/cTZSzp). Updated, thanks.

Comment: @CodeCaster I ran `Console.WriteLine("{17|100}", 1)` and got the message that the OP got.  I believe it's literally saying that `17|100` is not a number between 0 and the number of arguments.  I too, would have thought the pipe would throw it off, but it seems to see the value as a number somehow.

Comment: @juharr interesting. IdeOne uses Mono, which [throws different exceptions](http://ideone.com/uOie0v).

Comment: @CodeCaster  Someone got cute with their parsing of the format items. It gives the invalid message for `Console.WriteLine("{0foo}", 1)`, but the out of range for  `Console.WriteLine("{1foo}", 1)`.